# What is the best way to check for existence of array object with property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

An API returns an array of objects.

I need to extract a single value from the first object which matches a filter:

```
channel = booking.custom_fields.filter(f => f.id == 744)[0].value.trim()
```

This works, except when the filter matches nothing, the array is empty, or `value==null`.

The only way I know around this is:

```
channel = 
   booking.custom_fields.filter(f => f.id == 744).length>0 &&
   booking.custom_fields.filter(f => f.id == 744)[0].value &&
   booking.custom_fields.filter(f => f.id == 744)[0].value.trim()
```

(which returns `null` or `false` if there was a problem.)

But this is not elegant and a lot of repetition of code.

Is there a better way?

The only thing I can think of is `try/catch`:

```
try { channel = booking.custom_fields.filter(f => f.id == 744)[0].value.trim() } 
catch { channel = null }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `.find` *beforehand* - don't try to squash it all into one statement. If an item is found, assign the value to `channel` (else assign `null` to `channel`):

```
const possibleItem = booking.custom_fields.find(f => f.id == 744);
const channel = possibleItem && possibleItem.value ? possibleItem.value.trim() : null;
```

Comment: I find this more elegant: `try { channel = booking.custom_fields.filter(f => f.id == 744)[0].value.trim() } catch { channel = null }`

Comment: That requires making `channel` not a `const`, and `try/catch` unnecessarily requires unwinding the whole stack in case there's an error.

Comment: Actually it doesn't need to be `const` ... `var` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think this one should be a correct answer :

```
const channel = booking.custom_fields.some(e=>e.id==744&&e.value) ? booking.custom_fields.filter(f=>f.id==744)[0].value.trim() : null
```

Comment: This will fail if the `.value` property is null, which OP says is a possibility.